aws amplify No data source found named ElasticSearchDomain
I am trying to implement search nearby
so I have to add custom resolver as this doc
but when I run amplify push, I get this error :
Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete
Name: FindEstablishmentsResolver (AWS::AppSync::Resolver), Event Type: create, Reason: Resource handler returned message: "No data source found named ElasticSearchDomain (Service: AppSync, Status Code: 404, Request ID: xxxx)" (RequestToken: xxxx, HandlerErrorCode: NotFound), IsCustomResource: false

code inside :  api/xxxx/stacks/CustomResources.json
  "Resources": {
   
    "FindEstablishmentsResolver": {
      "Type": "AWS::AppSync::Resolver",
      "Properties": {
        "ApiId": {
          "Ref": "AppSyncApiId"
        },
        "DataSourceName": "ElasticSearchDomain",
        "TypeName": "Query",
        "FieldName": "findEstablishments",
        "RequestMappingTemplateS3Location": {
          "Fn::Sub": [
            "s3://${S3DeploymentBucket}/${S3DeploymentRootKey}/resolvers/Query.findEstablishments.req.vtl",
            {
              "S3DeploymentBucket": {
                "Ref": "S3DeploymentBucket"
              },
              "S3DeploymentRootKey": {
                "Ref": "S3DeploymentRootKey"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "ResponseMappingTemplateS3Location": {
          "Fn::Sub": [
            "s3://${S3DeploymentBucket}/${S3DeploymentRootKey}/resolvers/Query.findEstablishments.res.vtl",
            {
              "S3DeploymentBucket": {
                "Ref": "S3DeploymentBucket"
              },
              "S3DeploymentRootKey": {
                "Ref": "S3DeploymentRootKey"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },

